# How do I take an IEnumerable result and turn it into a List <treenode>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

How do I take an `IEnumerable` result and turn it into a `List<treenode>` in C#, .NET 4.0 and MVC

I have basically that same query running in two places and just want to hit database one time.  I run this query twice in dozens of places.

```
 using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(DBUtils._connStr))

 string sql = @"SELECT L.Name as Name, L.LocationTypeID as LocationTypeID, L.LocationID as LocationID, L.ParentLocationID as ParentLocationID, ISNULL(L.OrderByNumber, -10000) as SectionOrder, L.FromAddress as FromAddress,
         lojL.Name as Section, lojL.LocationID as SectionID,
                    ISNULL(lojL.Name + ' \ ','') + L.Name as NameWithSection
                    FROM hdLocations as L
              LEFT OUTER JOIN hdLocations as lojL ON L.ParentLocationID = lojL.LocationID
            WHERE L.LocationID > 0 AND L.InstanceID=0 And L.ParentLocationID =0";
sql += " ORDER BY  L.OrderByNumber, L.Name";

IEnumerable<TicketLocation> locations = cn.Query<TicketLocation>(sql);
```

The second is slightly different in that it only returns 4 columns to the `List<treenode>`

```
string sql = @"SELECT LocationID AS id, Name AS data, ParentLocationID, LocationTypeID FROM hdLocations WHERE ParentLocationID=0 AND LocationID > 0";
List<TreeNode> locs = cn.Query<TreeNode>(sql).ToList();
```

I am trying to limit this call, it happens to often in my application and Trying to just do it on log in and not every page load.

**EDIT**
I would like to do use the result of the first to build the second... something like

```
foreach (TicketLocation TL in locations)
{
    if ((TL.ParentLocationID == 0) && (TL.LocationID > 0))
    {
        TreeNode itemTreeNode = new TreeNode()
        {
            id = TL.LocationID,
            data = TL.Name,
        };
        itemTreeNode.id = TL.LocationID;
        itemTreeNode.data = TL.Name;
        itemTreeNode.parentId = TL.ParentLocationID;
        // itemTreeNode.

        locs.Add(itemTreeNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: what type is 'cn'?  what is the return type of 'cn.Query<T>()' ?

Comment: Do you want to generate `IEnumerable<TreeNode>` from `IEnumerable<TicketLocation>`?

Comment: cn is SQLConnection...

Comment: @ClaudioRedi something like that, yes.  See my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to make `IEnumerable<TicketLocation>` into `List<TicketLocation>`, all you need to do is just call `.ToList()` on it. As far as mapping from `TicketLocation` to `TreeNode` goes, what's wrong with the code you posted? You could simplify that code greatly though with something like:

```
var locs = locations.Where(m => m.ParentLocationID == 0 && m.LocationID > 0)
    .Select(m => new TreeNode
        {
            id = m.LocationID,
            data = m.Name,
            parentId = m.ParentLocationID
        }).ToList();
```

Which would result in `locs` being a `List<TreeNode>`.

Comment: I'd also mention that you also need to have the using clause `using System.Linq;` if you don't already have the using clause for [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Chris, I just couldn't find this.  Perfect.  I was a little hung up on the code that built the TreeNode had a 4th value in it.

Comment: It is good to mention the "using" as you did, Erik, as it can be hard to find!  Many people leave this out, also...